# Vue UI not working, Disconnected from UI server

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

i got some error when execute command to open vue ui,

[image]

[image]

i've try to fix but still got some error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using MS Edge.

In my case, I used a chromium browser as a default HTTP(S) application, and VUE UI did not work in that browser.
But I changed my default browser to Chrome, and Vue UI has started successfully.

**I recommend changing the default browser to Chrome.**
Most of the web development is based on it.
So when you make a new project, start with Chrome.

(And don't forget to install Vue devtool on your Chrome)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).